# Google analytics 'total events' and 'unique events' is not right

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm working with google analytics on my android application.

Sending a specific event shows a strange behavior where the sum of the events isn't reaching the 'total events' count. 
As seen below, total events = 369,579 but the sum of all the events is definitely not 369,579. Any idea why's that ? 
(I've tried filtering in a lot of ways, nothing seemed to give me valid results.

[image: analytics]

Answer (score 0):

The numbers at the top of the Event Label report are not what you think. Depending on how you navigated to that page, you could be seeing the mathematical sum of the rows shown OR the number in the row of the previous report that you clicked into.

I have written detailed explanations for the event report confusion in a couple of articles as part of my Misunderstood Metrics series:
http://help.analyticsedge.com/googleanalytics/misunderstood-metrics-events/
http://help.analyticsedge.com/googleanalytics/misunderstood-metrics-unique-events/

Comment: read your posts and it doesn't make scense. in your post you sum up the events and it is sums up to 35 in the end. will keep looking.